# What is the path, which environment variables do I need with anaconda python?

Tags: python, path, environment-variables, conda

I am relatively new to Python coding, and have bumped into setting environment variables and PATH often, but never really understood the meaning of it.

What is an environment variable, why do we need to specify a PATH, how is this linked to conda environments and, at the end of the day: which paths do I need to add in order to have a properly functioning miniconda installation?

Comment: environment variables are variables available in your operating system that can be shared by different programs.
You need specify a PATH so your OS knows where to look for your Python executable or libraries. That's why for example you can start Python by typing simply `python` in CMD instead of having to type `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe` every time you want to start your Python interpreter.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Answer (score 0):

What is an environment variable

As the name suggest its a variable that can be accessed from multiple application on the environment, for example both my C program and python program can read PATH and know where the main folder is

why do we need to specify a PATH

The system need to know where thing are installed so when it will look for modules/lib/file it will search at the correct location, also its an easy way to manage a folder structure on multiple computers. each user can save where he whats but the final location will be PATH/file/structure

how is this linked to conda environments and, at the end of the day

Each conda "env" can be viewed as a different PATH setting so under the anaconda folder you will have anaconda/myenv1/packages  or anaconda/myenv2/packages and when you are activating myenv1 you change the PATH to be anaconda/myenv1

which paths do I need to add in order to have a properly functioning miniconda installation?

follow the errors you get and add the paths of the libs to PATH="lib1:lib2:etc"